# AppendChild (Javascript) and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, appendchild, textnode

As a student and someone fairly new to web development, I'm experiencing the following seemingly strange problem in Javascript - but only in IE (IE9 to be precise; haven't yet tried IE10). In Firefox, the script works without any problems.

The code is like this:

```
item = document.createElement('li'); alert("alert1");
message = document.createTextNode("Hallo"); alert("alert2");
item.appendChild(message); alert("alert3");
```

In IE, alert1 and alert2 are shown, but not alert3. In other words, IE9 chokes on the third statement above (the appendChild), and never reaches alert3. Strange indeed.

Using Google, I've found that there are known problems with appendChild in IE (at least in earlier versions). But none of the problems described, or the workarounds suggested, seem to match my simple code, as cited above.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Edit to add: The console gives the following error message: "object doesn't support the property or method appendChild".

Comment: IE is designed to make it difficult and annoying. Try setting the innerHTMLof li instead.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with a simple fiddle (testing in IE9): http://jsfiddle.net/RnwPG/

Comment: @Teemu Interesting. I still would've expected the `item = docu...` line above to overwrite whatever `window.item` is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/html#methods) is a native method in IE's `window` object.

You can rename your variable, or declare it properly:

```
var item = document.createElement('li');
```

Comment: Yes, that solved it, great! Apparently I'm not supposed to say thanks here, but I'll say it anyway: thanks.

Comment: @Holland You're wellcome. Thanks are always nice to get, but the best thank is a green checkmark in the answer ; ).